# Entity Framework inserts instead of updating

Tags: entity-framework

I have an item and one of its properties is country which is an object, I thought I should be able to execute the below code.

```
var Post = new Post();

country = simpleRepository.GetCountries().FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryId == postViewModel.PostAddress.CountryId); 

post.PostAddress.Country = country;

allThingsEntities.Posts.Add(post);
```

Unfortunately I get this error when I do:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

And when I change `post.PostAddress.Country = country;` to `post.PostAddress.CountryId = country.countryId` the system throws an error because it seem to try to create a new country.

Comment: Can you please show us the `Post` and `PostAddress` classes?

Comment: What is `GetCountries()` doing? Possible to see this?

Comment: It seems like simpleRepository and allThinsEntities use different DbContexts/ObjectContexts. You recieve your country from one context and try to add it to another. You must detach the country from the simpleRepsitorys context first, then attach it to allThingsEntities, then assign it to PostAddress.Country.

Answer (score 0):

That error means you have multiple data context instances.You might wana do something like this, to maintain only one instance.Call this from your Repos.

```
public DataContext Get()
{
    return _dataContext ?? (dataContext = new DataContext());
}
```